# What is the problem with my Oracle DataBase sequence?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I made a table and tried to apply sequence.
But there is a red line under the START WITH 1.
What is the problem?

```
create table memo (
    memoId number(4) primary key,
    nickName nvarchar2(20),
    contents nvarchar2(200),
    regTime timestamp
);

commit;

select * from memo;

create sequence memo_seq 
START WITH 1  
INCREMENT BY 1 
NOMAXVALUE  
NOCACHE;
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with it. See https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=c5d7a0af28cd2ed8a8dc66cf38488578. Must be a glitch in your text editor.

Comment: @TheImpaler there's noting glitch.

Comment: You've tagged this Javascript but there appears to be no Javascript code.  You've tagged this for both Eclipse and SQL Developer.  Presumably you aren't using two different IDEs.  My guess is that you're actually using SQL Developer and not Eclipse but that's just a guess.  What tool is adding the "red line" you talk about?  Are you running the script?  Is Oracle giving an error?

Comment: @JustinCave Oh i am sorry. That is SQLDeveloper.

Comment: Paste the code in notepad once to remove any junk characters.

Comment: Why use nocache? Is performance not important?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong - except maybe with SQL Developer wrongly recognizing a non-existent error. Because - as you already know (if you ran that statement) - sequence gets created.

(Sorry for taking a photo, but - I just don't know how to take a screenshot because that "Syntax error" *tooltip* disappears if I press the Print Screen button on the keyboard.)

[image]

Comment: I am using Mac OS so there isn't any print Screen key. Hhm....